# Responsive thumbnails with bootstrap and/or jquery? (Dynamically resize?)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, thumbnails, image-resizing

I thought I had this problem worked out previously, but I guess not.

In my example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/VDtgT/31/

I would have thought that the image being called within the span div would be constrained/resized by the max-height & min-height settings of the div?

I'm basically intending to have a row of DB output with a single image in it, but it needs to scale that image based on the size of the window.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">

<!-- *** TOP ROW -->
<div class="row-fluid show-grid">
<div class="span12" style="background-color: yellow;" align="center">HEADER ROW</div>
</div> 



<!-- *** MIDDLE ROW --->
<div class="row-fluid">

    <div class="span4 boxitup">
    <a href="#"> <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="img1"></a> 
    </div>
<div class="span4 boxitup">Column 2</div>
<div class="span4 boxitup">Column 3</div>
</div>    


    </div> <!-- /close wrap --> 

<div id="push"></div>

<!-- FOOTER BEGIN --> 

<div id="footer">

<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span12" style="background-color: yellow;" align="center">
    Footer row
</div>
</div>
    </div>
```

the javascript:

```
$( document ).ready( function(){
setMaxHeight();
$( window ).bind( "resize", setMaxHeight );  

function setMaxHeight() {
$( ".boxitup" ).css( "min-height", ($(window).height() / 7) + "px" );   
$( ".boxitup" ).css( "max-height", ($(window).height() / 7) + "px" );   
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the image to fill its enclosing box, just add the following to your css:

```
img {
      height:100%;
}
```

You can view the result [here in my fork of your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/cPLXH/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You are setting max and min heights the same, which when I opened demo was 42px.

In order to not see contents that are larger than container you need to set css `overflow:hidden`.

All that you are seeing is the overflow. Not entirely clear why you are targeting rows and not the images, or why you are setting max and min heights the same